# How to unwind data held in edges with a "common neighbors" style query?

Tags: arangodb, aql, arangojs

I have a simple model with a single `A` Document collection

```
[{ _key: 'doc1', id: 'a/doc1', name: 'Doc 1' }, { _key: 'doc2', id: 'a/doc2', name: 'Doc 2' }]
```

and a single `B` Edge collection, joining documents `A` with an held `weight` integer on each edge.

```
[{ _key: 'xxx', id: 'b/xxx', _from: 'a/doc1', _to: 'a/doc2', weight: 256 }]
```

---

I'm trying to make a "common neighbors" style query, that takes 2 document as an input, and yields common neighbors of those inputs, along with respective weights (of each side).

For example with `doc1` and `doc26` input, here is the goal to achieve :

```
[
  { _key: 'doc6', weightWithDoc1: 43, weightWithDoc26: 57 },
  { _key: 'doc12', weightWithDoc1: 98, weightWithDoc26: 173 },
  { _key: 'doc21', weightWithDoc1: 3, weightWithDoc26: 98 },
]
```

I successfully started by targeting a single side :

```
FOR associated, association
  IN 1..1
  ANY ${d1}
  ${EdgeCollection}
  SORT association.weight DESC
  LIMIT 20
  RETURN { _key: associated._key, weight: association.weight }
```

Then successfully went on with the `INTERSECTION` logic of the documentation

```
FOR proj IN INTERSECTION(
  (FOR associated, association
    IN 1..1
    ANY ${d1}
    ${EdgeCollection}
    RETURN { _key: associated._key }),
  (FOR associated, association
    IN 1..1
    ANY ${d2}
    ${EdgeCollection}
    RETURN { _key: associated._key })
)
LIMIT 20
RETURN proj
```

---

But I'm now struggling at extracting the `weight` of each side, as unwinding it on the inner `RETURN` clauses will make them exclusive on the intersection; thus returning nothing.

Questions :

1. Is there any way to make some kind of "selective `INTERSECTION`", grouping some fields in the process ?
2. Is there an alternative to `INTERSECTION` to achieve my goal ?

Bonus question :

3. Ideally, after successfully extracting `weightWithDoc1` and `weightWithDoc26`, I'd like to `SORT DESC` by `weightWithDoc1 + weightWithDoc26`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an acceptable answer myself

```
FOR associated IN INTERSECTION(
  (FOR associated
    IN 1..1
    ANY ${doc1}
    ${EdgeCollection}
    RETURN { _key: associated._key }),
  (FOR associated
    IN 1..1
    ANY ${doc2}
    ${EdgeCollection}
    RETURN { _key: associated._key })
)
LET association1 = FIRST(FOR association IN ${EdgeCollection}
  FILTER association._from == CONCAT(${DocCollection.name},'/',MIN([${doc1._key},associated._key])) AND association._to == CONCAT(${DocCollection.name},'/',MAX([${doc1._key},associated._key]))
  RETURN association)
LET association2 = FIRST(FOR association IN ${EdgeCollection}
  FILTER association._from == CONCAT(${DocCollection.name},'/',MIN([${doc2._key},associated._key])) AND association._to == CONCAT(${DocCollection.name},'/',MAX([${doc2._key},associated._key]))
  RETURN association)
SORT (association1.weight+association2.weight) DESC
LIMIT 20
RETURN { _key: associated._key, weight1: association1.weight, weight2: association2.weight }
```

I believe re-selecting after intersecting is not ideal and not the most performant solution, so I'm leaving it open for now to wait for a better answer.